# Is there any reason why Leaflet rounds pixel coordinates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I wonder that some of leaflet projection methods e.g.  [`latLngToLayerPoint`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0d06c4256f4312a7122c23626c8bd36e14269d01/src/map/Map.js#L1014) and [`_setPos`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/a55bec8835387b6168d0ef34ebccb3cf601acee4/src/layer/marker/Marker.js#L194) method of `Marker` rounds pixel coordinates.

Is there any reason why? It would be nice not to round, because we can take better positioning and more smooth marker animations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is pixel fidelity: making sure that one pixel from an image (a tile or a marker icon) corresponds exactly to one pixel in your screen.

This is best explained with a counter-example: some browsers (notably Chrome) perform pixel interpolation when an image (or the container of an image) has a fractional offset.

Let's take for example the map that appears on the leafletjs.com homepage, hit the browser's developer tools...

[image: Original leaflet map]

...and change the offset of the main map pane by *half a pixel*:

[image: Leaflet map with non-integer offsets]

It *looks blurry*. In case your eyesight or your screen doesn't let you appreciate the difference, here's what it looks like when magnified:

[image: Side-by-side blurry and non-blurry maps]

While the browser is doing exactly what it's being asked of (moving an image half a pixel), that means that each pixel on the screen is the weighted combination of four pixels from the source tile images (because the webkit engine uses a linear interpolation). Other browsers (e.g. Firefox) don't display this behaviour (because they use a nearest-neighbour approach).

Even though Leaflet is using integer offsets by default, there are some setups (a combination of hi-res screens plus panning animations plus browser setup) that still causes this blurriness; see for example [Leaflet bug #6069](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6069). Subpixel stuff in general is a PITA to deal with (see [Leaflet bug #3575](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3575)).

Using non-integer offsets would make that kind of bugs more prominent.

Comment: Of course objects static positioning is the primary case in leaflet, but rounding makes animations a bit rough, which is my case. So I've created a little plugin to extend `L.Marker` with `setLatLngPrecise` method, which has a subpixel accuracy. https://github.com/itanka9/l-subpixel-position/tree/master